# Connect DocuSign to Dynamics

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, docusignapi, dynamics-365

What type of account is needed specifically to complete the Connect "DocuSign to Dynamics"? In reference to page 7 step 3 of the DocuSign for Dynamics 365 CRM Quick Start Guide.  That guide states it has to be an admin user.

Is this a Dynamics 365 System Administrator or a Global Administrator. If it is a Global Administrator what access mode is required? (Administrative, Read-Write, or Non-Interactive). If it is Read-Write does this need to be a permanent account?

When I try to connect with my account as a Dynamics 365 System Administrator I get the following message:

> You can't access this application
>
> DocuSign for Dynamics needs permission to access resources in your
>   organization that only an admin can grant. Please ask an admin to
>   grant permission to this app before you can use it.

When I try to use the Microsoft Admin account (global admin) with Administrative access mode I get an error:

> An unknown error has occurred. Please contact support at
>   support@docusign.com.
>
> https://partner.docusign.net/partners/msdynamics/error?message=System.ServiceModel.FaultException%601%5bMicrosoft.Xrm.Sdk.OrganizationServiceFault%5d%3a+Principal+user+(Id%*GUIDHERE*%2c+type%3d8)+is+missing+prvReaddocusign_accountconfiguration+privilege+(Id%GUIDHEREe)+(Fault+Detail+is+equal+to+Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.OrganizationServiceFault).

Comment: Did you try to promote the global admin into System admin  for this to work?

Comment: Global Admin is a Dynamics System Admin, with Access Mode set to Administrative.  Those are the questions I need answered as we evaluate the product.  We want to know the specifics of the account required to make the connection, is it permanent, and why it needs to be a global admin at all and not just a system admin service/integration account.